# how to hide bar charts in mysql data without being deleted

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, bar-chart

I want to ask how to hide data appears on website (bar chart), but without deleting data on mysql

this is code for show the bar chart

```
  // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
  google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {

    // Create the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'storage_type');
    data.addColumn('number', 'storage_used');
    data.addColumn('number', 'storage_free');
    for(i = 0; i < my_2d.length; i++)
data.addRow([my_2d[i][0], parseInt(my_2d[i][1]),parseInt(my_2d[i][2])]);

    var options = {
      title: 'server'
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
   }
```

and this a output that code
[image]

i just want to show bar chart "fujitsu" and hide "hp" and "huawei" but without delete the database on mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgyFv.png)

Answer (score 1):

It's not hard to filter your data as you render it. This is a job for a filter array containing the names of the items you want to show, and the [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) function.

```
 const storage_type_filter = [ 'fujitsu' ];

 for(let i = 0; i < my_2d.length; i++) {
     const storage_type = my_2d[i][0];
     const storage_used = parseInt(my_2d[i][1]);
     const storage_free = parseInt(my_2d[i][1]);
     if (storage_type_filter.includes(storage_type)) {
         data.addRow (storage_type, storage_used, storage_free);
     }
 }
```

You didn't show us anything about your database. But you can also filter your data with something like `WHERE storage_type IN ('fujitsu')` as you retrieve it.

**Pro tip** the next person to work on this report will be really happy if you use descriptive variable names.

Comment: sorry jones, database has been added